# An error occurs during npm I java in node

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

```
npm ERR! path /Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/java
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.2.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/java/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/name/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.2.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/name/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.2.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/name/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.2.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/java',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/java.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/java.h:9:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:176:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_callbacks.h:55:23: error: no member named 'AccessorSignature' in namespace 'v8'
npm ERR! typedef v8::Local<v8::AccessorSignature> Sig;
npm ERR!                   ~~~~^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/java.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/java.h:9:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:682:39: warning: 'IdleNotificationDeadline' is deprecated: Use MemoryPressureNotification() to influence the GC schedule. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!     return v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()->IdleNotificationDeadline(
npm ERR!                                       ^
npm ERR! /Users/name/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.2.0/include/node/v8-isolate.h:1291:3: note: 'IdleNotificationDeadline' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR!   V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! /Users/name/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.2.0/include/node/v8config.h:550:39: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
npm ERR! # define V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
npm ERR!                                       ^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/java.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/java.h:9:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:2535:8: error: no matching member function for call to 'SetAccessor'
npm ERR!   tpl->SetAccessor(
npm ERR!   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! /Users/name/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.2.0/include/node/v8-template.h:816:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'imp::Sig' (aka 'int') to 'v8::SideEffectType' for 7th argument
npm ERR!   void SetAccessor(
npm ERR!        ^
npm ERR! /Users/name/Library/Caches/node-gyp/20.2.0/include/node/v8-template.h:809:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'imp::NativeGetter' (aka 'void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &)') to 'v8::AccessorGetterCallback' (aka 'void (*)(Local<v8::String>, const PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &)') for 2nd argument
npm ERR!   void SetAccessor(
npm ERR!        ^
npm ERR! 1 warning and 2 errors generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:511:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/20.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/name/Desktop/node.js_v2.6/node_modules/java
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

global version
node: 20.2.0
node-gyp: 9.3.1
Python 3.11.3

I tried to match the version of Java, Python, node-gyp, but I couldn't find information.

how can i ?

Comment: How can you what?

Comment: I tried to match the version of Java, Python, node-gyp, but I couldn't find any information.

How can I use " npm i " command to install Java?

I need to install Java in node.js

Comment: " I need to install Java in node.js" -- Han. That's not how node.js works. Could you elaborate on _why_ you need to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.